# How to define word/WORD boundaries?

Tags: vimrc

I'm familiar with iskeyword to define word boundaries. But there's also WORD and I don't know what the setting is for that. My goal is this: to delete words in a comma-seperate list flexibly. Example:

```
apple, banana, carrot, orange.
```

If I place my cursor at carrot and type `daw`, I expect it to remove `carrot,•` (space represented by the `•` symbol). If I type `diw` instead, I expect it to remove just `carrot`. Is this possible?

I currently have `set iskeyword-=,` but that makes both commands do the same thing, except one doesn't delete a space.

Comment: `daW` gets you the desired behavior (note the capital).

Comment: Why didn't you answer this question? I could've selected it as the answer. Do you want to answer it?

Comment: Because I fixed your problem without answering your question. :P But if you're satisfied I'll answer it.

Comment: I think you did answer my question. You told me how to use word boundaries properly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to modify `iskeyword`. You can just use a WORD instead. You can use a WORD (as opposed to a word) in a text object by using a capital W:

```
daW
```

See [`:help text-objects`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects) and [`:help WORD`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD) for more info.